# How to change props value in child component form parent component VUE?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

i have a problem to handle dynamic props in vue with typescript, here is my parent component

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const friends = [
  {
    id: "emanuel",
    name: "Emanuella e",
    phone: "08788",
    email: "emanuella@gmail.com",
    isFavorite: true,
  },
  {
    id: "denta",
    name: "Denta W",
    phone: "08789",
    email: "denta@gmail.com",
    isFavorite: false,
  },
];

function toggleFavorite(friendId:any){
  console.log(friendId);
  const identifiedFriend= friends.find(friend=>friend.id === friendId);
  if(identifiedFriend!=undefined){
    identifiedFriend.isFavorite=!identifiedFriend.isFavorite
  }
  console.log(identifiedFriend);
}
</script>

<template>
  <section>
    <header><h1>Test Friends</h1></header>
    <ul>
      <friend-container
        v-for="friend in friends"
        :id="friend.id"
        :key="friend.id"
        :name="friend.name"
        :phone="friend.phone"
        :email="friend.email"
        :isFavorite="friend.isFavorite"
        @toggle-favorite="toggleFavorite"
      >
      </friend-container>
    </ul>
  </section>
</template>
```

and here is my child component

```
<template>
  <li>
    <h2>{{ name }} {{ isFavorite ? "(Favorite)" : "" }}</h2>
    <button @click="toggleFavorite">Toggle Favorite</button>
    <button @click="toggleDetails">Show details</button>
  
    <ul v-if="detailAreVisible">
      <li><strong>Phone: </strong>{{ phone }}</li>
      <li><strong>email: </strong>{{ email }}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

import { ref} from 'vue';

const detailAreVisible=ref(false);

const props = defineProps<{
  id: { type: String; required: true };
  name: { type: String; required: true };
  phone: { type: String; required: true };
  email: { type: String; required: true };
  isFavorite: Boolean
}>();

const emit=defineEmits<{
    (e: 'toggle-favorite', value: any): void
}>()
function toggleDetails(){
    detailAreVisible.value=!detailAreVisible.value
}

function toggleFavorite(){
    emit("toggle-favorite",props.id);
  
}
</script>
```

i already change the props data in parent component using emit event handling, but in my child component, isFavorite value still cant change, am i miss something or how to handle it? sorry im new in vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state `friends` should be declared with `reactive` in order to respond to the changes, and you should also reduce the attributes binding by using only [`v-bind` with multiple attributes](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#dynamically-binding-multiple-attributes) since the prop names are the same as state keys :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import {reactive} from 'vue'

const friends = reactive([
  {
    id: "emanuel",
    name: "Emanuella e",
    phone: "08788",
    email: "emanuella@gmail.com",
    isFavorite: true,
  },
  {
    id: "denta",
    name: "Denta W",
    phone: "08789",
    email: "denta@gmail.com",
    isFavorite: false,
  },
]);

function toggleFavorite(friendId:any){
  console.log(friendId);
  const identifiedFriend= friends.find(friend=>friend.id === friendId);
  if(identifiedFriend != undefined){
    identifiedFriend.isFavorite = !identifiedFriend.isFavorite
  }
  console.log(identifiedFriend);
}
</script>

<template>
  <section>
    <header><h1>Test Friends</h1></header>
    <ul>
      <friend-container
        v-for="friend in friends"
        :key="friend.id"
         v-bind="friend"
        @toggle-favorite="toggleFavorite"
      >
      </friend-container>
    </ul>
  </section>
</template>
```

Comment: whoaa its solved for me, thank you very much, I think I need to learn a lot more about Vue especially in typescript